# rendering the partials in controller after the validation check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have two partial views for two different sign up forms. On my home page , based on the link one clicks on, I'm rendering respective form.(views/application/index)

```
= link_to 'Mentor', new_user_path(user_role: true), :class =>'btn'
= link_to 'Mentee', new_user_path, :class =>'btn'
```

In views/users/new.html.haml , I'm checking the user role and redirecting to the respective form.

```
- if params[:user_role]
= render 'mentor'
- else
= render 'mentee'
```

In the user model I've added validation like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@cisco.com/i

    validates :cisco_email, :presence   => true,
              :format     => { :with => email_regex,}
    validates :work_city, :presence => true

end
```

So, when there is any invalid field I want to direct to the same form with a flash message. My controller looks like this.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def index
   end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

   def new
     @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])    # Not the final implementation!
        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to the CSG Mentoring Tool!"
            redirect_to @user
        else 
        flash[:notice] = "Error regsitering."

             if params[:user][:user_role]
                      render :partial => 'users/mentor'
             else
                render :partial => 'users/mentee'
             end
         end
     end    
 end
```

When an invalid field entry is there, it is redirecting to 'mentee' page no matter on which page the error is made. Also the entire css styling gets changed and flash is also not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this is not working?
     if params[:user][:user_role]
        render :partial => 'users/mentor'
     else
        render :partial => 'users/mentee'
     end

`params[:user][:user_role]` is nil.

You can check it using lots of way:

Above your if condition `raise params[:user].inspect`

**Why its nil?**

Reason of this is You are passing `new_user_path(user_role: true)` user_role true, but user_role is not true in mentor form.

`params[:user_role]` will not set `user_role = true` field in mentor form.

Set user_role

`<%=f.hidden_field :user_role, value: params[:user_role] %>`

If its supposed to be true for mentor always

`<%=f.hidden_field :user_role, value: true %>`

By default flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request.
[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

**This works with redirection**

```
flash[:success] = "Welcome to the CSG Mentoring Tool!"
```

**This will work with render**

```
flash.now[:success] = "Welcome to the CSG Mentoring Tool!"
```

Comment: Thanks @pradeep. I was wondering how to set the user_role = true in mentor form so that this won't happen. Any way that you could guide me into ?

Comment: Thanks @pradeep. But I still wonder why the entire layout changes when I'm rendering partials from controller.

Comment: render don't reload css and js again. It depends on how you are using css and js in your application. It would be easy to answer after seeing your partials and how you are including css and js..

Comment: @pradeep. I have application.html.haml in my layouts folder. I have a basic js and css and linkinng them to the application.html.haml file. When I checked the source code of the partial I'm rendering the layout (which links to jjs and css) is missing .

Comment: @pradeep. I was just going through a couple of posts on rendering partials and found the solution. Thanks for your help.